# Complex string split method in java

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, singly-linked-list

basically, I am trying to be able to read every line separated by some conditions (\n \s , )and store the String into Node A and Node B for the purpose of node addition, but not sure where to start or figured out what to do. please Help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        String oneLine;
        FileReader theFile = new FileReader("src/Test.txt");
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(theFile);
        Node A = new Node(0,null);

        while((oneLine = inFile.readLine()) != null) {

            String numbers[]= oneLine.split("\n");

            for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                 int a = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
                 A.addNumtoNode(a); } } }

public void addNumtoNode(int e){
        head = new Node(e,head);
        if (size == 0)
        tail = head; 
        size++;
        }
```

Sample of Test.txt

```
9
4

31,415,926,535
2

0
1,234,567,890

1,734,792
131

1,506,033,005,018,000,029
1,992
```

Comment: Is Node your custom class? If so, then please post it

Comment: Is the third nonblank line supposed to be one number (31415926535), or four numbers?  In any event, I have no idea what you're trying to do.  You talk about adding to Nodes but don't give us any idea what a Node is.  We don't know what results you're expecting, or why it isn't working.  I don't know what "separated by some conditions" means, and I don't know what the \s is doing in your question.  And I don't know what you mean by "Node addition".  Basically, you are giving us nothing to work with.

Comment: that's the line number 4 and supposed to be 4 numbers. for example 31 -> 415 -> 926 -> 535 to be add to node 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String#split()` takes regular expression as delimiter.

Use regex `\D+` it means One or more Non digit.

So just change `String numbers[]= oneLine.split("\n")`
 to  :

```
 if (oneLine.isEmpty()) {
      continue;
 }
 String numbers[]= oneLine.split("\\D+");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that show should split the line using ','. readLine() splits the text in lines and then you want the numbers of that line that are separated by ','.

Comment: if I use ',' then it will give me error when reading the first line.. so I need to make sure to apply some condition such as whitespace, enter or ','